# lucky number while loop won't repeat

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that lets the user guess a random number 15 times, then it tells the user if they guessed it correctly or not. I used a while loop to make it so that it repeats while they're guessing and gives them a hint about whether it is too low or high. But instead of repeating, it just gives them the feedback and ends. How do I get my loop to repeat until they run out of chances?

```
from random import randint 
 chances = 15
guesses = 0
lucky = randint in range (0,100)

guess = int(input("Guess a number between 0 and 100: "))
while chances > 0:
  if guess > lucky:
    chances =- 1 
    guesses =+ 1
    print("too high")
    guess = int(input("Guess a number "))
  elif guess < lucky:
    chances =- 1 
    guesses =+ 1
    print("too low")
    guess = int(input("Guess a number "))
  else:
    guesses =+ 1
    break


if guess == lucky:
  print("you guessed it in", guesses,"guesses. good job!")

if guess != lucky and chances == 0:
  print("Sorry, you didn't get it. The lucky number was", lucky)
```

Comment: `chances =- 1` is the same thing as `chances = -1`.  You want `-=` there (and likewise `+=` on `guesses`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
lucky = randint in range(0, 100)
```

To:

```
lucky = randint(0, 100)
```

And every occurrence of:

```
chances = - 1
```

to:

```
chances -= 1
```

Same goes for:

```
guesses = + 1
```

to:

```
guesses += 1
```

And your program will work!

The reason your program didn't print anything was the fact that you assigned -1 to `chances` and in the last `if` you checked if `chances == 0` but since it was lower than 0 - nothing was printed.

Comment: So I changed that but the guesses still aren't going up. it tells them that it only took one guess, when it took more than that. How can I fix that?

Comment: @savannah if you changed it and it's not going up it means that you forgot to fix it in one of the places. When I fixed all the above and ran locally it worked fine.